# Should I use "So can´t I" or "neither can I"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

If someone tells me "I can´t do the homework because it is too hard, but can you(me) do it?" and I want to say that I can´t do it too should I answer "So can´t I" or "neither can I"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I can´t do the homework because it is too hard, but can you do it?" and I want to say that I can´t do it too should I answer "So can´t I"or "neither can I"*

You might say that but it would not be as natural as saying:

***'no, I can't'*** or ***'I can't either'*** or possibly ***'no, I can't do it either'*** (a bit long, though).

If your friend says something negative and you agree with them you can use **'neither'** or **'nor'**.

**For example:**

**Your friend:** *I don't like John.*
**You:** *Nor do I/ neither do I.*

If your friend says something positive and you agree with them you can use **'so'**.

**For example:**

**Your friend:** *I like Alice.*
**You:** *So do I.*

Answer (score 3):

You can say "neither can I." or "I can't either." In the first case, the negation is in the word "neither"; in the second case, it is contracted with the verb "can".